# Django: get result of raw SQL query in one line

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, psycopg2

This works:

```
connection = get_connection()
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('show application_name')
application_name_of_connection=cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

But why four lines? Is there no way to get this in one line?

Comment: I've never seen a language which makes it possible to connect, query, and get a result set in a single line.  Why do you want this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want this, since I want my code to be simple and easy to read. ("I hate code, and I want as little of it as possible in our product." – Jack Diederich)

Comment: One of arguments against the move to functional style, in languages such as Java, is that while it reduces the number of lines of code, it increases the complexity of the fewer lines of code.  Everything is a trade-off.

Comment: application_name_of_connection = get_connection().cursor().execute('show application_name').fetchone()[0] Try this.

Comment: In good python practices one line of code means one line of thought. So this is why you have this four lines for doing this task, each line represents general step which is need to be done to get your data. I don't see problem wrapping this in function and calling it whenever you need this four lines to be executed

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev My line of tought is: get the value from DB.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi executing this in one lines seems not to work: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'` The method `execute()` does not return the cursor object :-(

Comment: Thats what functions for

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a way to do this in one line. Languages such as Python are designed to describe a set of instructions. There are four instructions here. There may even be helper methods or clever/inefficient arrangements of these statements that could lower this to three lines, but you are best to keep it how it is.

For example, if you are for some reason using this code frequently, you would encapsulate it in its own method

```
def get_application_name_of_connection()
    connection = get_connection()
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('show application_name')
    return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

And then simply:

```
get_application_name_of_connection()
```

This is how it works. You want less code? Hide the functionality.

Comment: Imagine I want to get about ten values like this: postgres server version, datetime of server, number of allowed connections ..... I think a method like "get single value from sql query" would result into the code with the fewest lines.

Comment: Sure, if such a method was provided by Django, it would. Unfortunately, it is not. Remember that behind the scenes, all of these "short" methods like `get_connection()` is actually hundreds of lines of code. You can write your own method to do this, but the total code you have written will be necessarily larger than one line.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with comprehension but on **sqlite**:

```
results = [row[0] for row in get_connection().cursor().execute('select * from mytable')]
```

If you are using postgresql then it doesn't work, you could try this for a more compact form:

```
with get_connection().cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute('show all')
    print cur.fetchone()
```

But **only** if you need the cursor thrown away after the block execution.

I didn't tried on other db managers, results may vary.